# CkEditor inline toolbar with iframe

Tags: iframe, ckeditor, inline, toolbar

I would like something similar to the CkEditor inline editor floating toolbar when creating the editor instance using the appendTo method. When using the inline variant of CkEditor, you will share CSS with the rest of the page. This is unfortunate when you want a different style for the page and the editor content. The other editor creation methods create an iframe for the editor content.

Is there a way to get the same floating toolbar behavior when not using inline editing for CkEditor?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: I did. The solution ended up pretty complex, but it works relatively well. Take a look at the Shared Space plugin if you want to try something similar yourself: http://ckeditor.com/addon/sharedspace

Comment: @StigRunarVangen can you share the code for this? I'm also trying this and running into issues...